# R changing values of long integers?

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to read tweet id numbers into R from a MySQL database.  These are 18-digit numbers, saved as BIGINT in the database.

When reading them in, something strange is happening: Maybe 20% of them are showing a value of 1 less than the actual number.  This is a problem for what I'm doing.

This change seems to be unrelated to the fact that the data is coming from MySQL, and more due to the fact that the data is 18 digits long, because the same thing happens if I just assign values to variables directly in R.

An easy-to-replicate example is:

```
options(scipen=20)

# This one changes
a <- 691363779729182721
a
[1] 691363779729182720

# This one doesn't change
b <- 691363809076711424
b
[1] 691363809076711424
```

Question 1:
Is there any way to prevent the values from changing arbitrarily?

The obvious solution I can figure out (which would work for my current purposes) is to read these numbers in as character class data.  Although from what I can see in the documentation for RMySQL there is no way to coerce BIGINT to character - it's read in as double class.

```
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user', password='password', db_name='Twitter', host='localhost')
sql <- 'SELECT twitter_id FROM Original_tweets'
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, sql)
# Nothing like colClasses for this next step??
tweet_ids <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
```

My other option, I guess, is to modify the database structure and put these numbers into a CHAR field in the database.

I would much prefer to just read the values into R from the current table and have them give the correct value, if that can be accomplished.

If it makes a difference, I am running R 3.2.3 on OSX 10.11.3.

Thank you,

Comment: The `gmp` package has a `bigz` class that will be useful if you can get it in as character.

Comment: To handle large integers, the [bit64](http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/web/packages/bit64/index.html) package may help.

Comment: You should handle these as characters when reading from data.

Comment: @42- Agreed, as `as.integer64('691363779729182721')` will give you the correct result but `as.integer64(691363779729182721)` will give you `691363779729182720` (not correct).